# BufferOverflowException while sending data of specific size

Tags: java, arrays, buffer-overflow, bytebuffer

I have bunch of keys and values that I want to send to our messaging queue by packing them in one byte array. I will make one byte array of all the keys and values which should always be less than 50K and then send to our messaging queue. I have header and then followed by data.

**Packet class**:

```
public final class Packet implements Closeable {
  private static final int MAX_SIZE = 50000;
  private static final int HEADER_SIZE = 36;

  private final byte dataCenter;
  private final byte recordVersion;
  private final long address;
  private final long addressFrom;
  private final long addressOrigin;
  private final byte recordsPartition;
  private final byte replicated;
  private final ByteBuffer itemBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
  private int pendingItems = 0;

  public Packet(final RecordPartition recordPartition) {
    this.recordsPartition = (byte) recordPartition.getPartition();
    this.dataCenter = Utils.LOCATION.getDatacenter();
    this.recordVersion = 1;
    this.replicated = 0;
    final long packedAddress = new Data().packAddress();
    this.address = packedAddress;
    this.addressFrom = 0L;
    this.addressOrigin = packedAddress;
  }

  private void addHeader(final ByteBuffer buffer, final int items) {
    buffer.put(dataCenter).put(recordVersion).putInt(items).putInt(buffer.capacity())
        .putLong(address).putLong(addressFrom).putLong(addressOrigin).put(recordsPartition)
        .put(replicated);
  }

  private void sendData() {
    if (itemBuffer.position() == 0) {
      // no data to be sent
      return;
    }
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
    addHeader(buffer, pendingItems);
    // below line throws "BufferOverflowException"
    buffer.put(itemBuffer);
    SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueAsync(address, buffer.array());
    itemBuffer.clear();
    pendingItems = 0;
  }

  public void addAndSendJunked(final byte[] key, final byte[] data) {
    if (key.length > 255) {
      return;
    }
    final byte keyLength = (byte) key.length;
    final byte dataLength = (byte) data.length;

    final int additionalSize = dataLength + keyLength + 1 + 1 + 8 + 2;
    final int newSize = itemBuffer.position() + additionalSize;
    if (newSize >= (MAX_SIZE - HEADER_SIZE)) {
      sendData();
    }
    if (additionalSize > (MAX_SIZE - HEADER_SIZE)) {
      throw new AppConfigurationException("Size of single item exceeds maximum size");
    }

    final ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    final long timestamp = dataLength > 10 ? dataBuffer.getLong(2) : System.currentTimeMillis();
    // data layout
    itemBuffer.put((byte) 0).put(keyLength).put(key).putLong(timestamp).putShort(dataLength)
        .put(data);
    pendingItems++;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    if (pendingItems > 0) {
      sendData();
    }
  }
}
```

In the above code, I am getting `java.nio.BufferOverflowException` at `buffer.put(itemBuffer);` in `sendData` method. I am not able to understand why I am getting this exception and how to fix it.

Here is how I am calling this code:

```
Packet packet = new Packet(partition);
packet.addAndSendJunked("hello".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StringUtils.EMPTY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
packet.close();
```

Comment: it means your buffer has less size than the itemBuffer

Comment: you should be able to set a breakpoint on that line and see the sizes for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly `itemBuffer` plus the length of the headers already put into `buffer` exceeds `buffer.capacity()`, i.e. MAX_SIZE.

*Ergo* either there is a bug in `addHeader()` or whatever creates `itemBuffer`, or MAX_SIZE is too small.

NB

```
SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueAsync(address, buffer.array());
```

Here you are enqueueing the entire `buffer`, of MAX_SIZE bytes, even though you may not have put MAX_SIZE bytes into it. It would be better to pass `buffer` itself to this method and avoid the ceaseless wraps in your code.

Comment: I think we need to flip "itemBuffer" before putting it into "buffer" after analyzing it more. Also how can I extract only what's been filled instead of sending everything to "sendToQueueAsync" method?

Comment: @user1950349 That is correct: `flip()` must precede `get()` or `write()`, or `put()` into another buffer. I've already answered your last question: don't.